# Creating programmatically a UINavigationController with UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have been struggling a quite long time with this problem. Maybe you could help me. So i want to create programmatically a basic UINavigationController with simple UITableView.

For example UITableView will contain some info about "Colors". Item list would be something like: "Yellow", "Orange", "Green", "Purple".

I would be really really happy if you can help me to get this right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@interface MyViewController: UITableViewController {
    NSArray *data;
}

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [data release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(int)s
{
    return [data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELLID"];
    if (!cell) cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault identifier:@"CELLID"] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:ip.row];
    return cell;
}


@end
```

Use it like:

```
MyViewController *ctrl = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ctrl];
[ctrl release];
```

etc.